# Can't get Indian Rupees symbol to show up in PDF generated with Flying Saucer

Tags: pdf, unicode, utf-8, flying-saucer

I'm trying a few different ways, but I can't get a pdf generated with Flying Saucer (from an html file) to show the unicode character for Indian Rupees - "₹"

This is what I have currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial Unicode MS, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial, verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
      }      

      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
        src: url(arialunicodems.ttf);
        -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
        -fs-pdf-font-encoding: UTF-8;
        -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
        font-weight: normal;
      }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <p>We want to see a Indian Rupees symbol between the asterisks on one or more of these lines, in the PDF (if any of the symbols make it through to the PDF then we're good):</p>
    <p>Using the glyph itself in the markup: * ₹ *</p>
    <p>Using &amp;#x20B9; in the markup: * &#x20B9; *</p>
    <p>Using &amp;#8377; in the markup: * &#8377; *</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

which represents lots of different experiments, none of which have worked.    The font file it refers to is sitting next to the html file version of the above.

The font itself seems to be being loaded, in that the text in the pdf file looks like Arial.  It's just missing the Rupees symbol.  I don't know what else to do - i'm pulling in a unicode font, and the html file itself looks fine, when viewed in the browser.  When I print it out of chrome it looks fine too, so the problem is definitely with flying saucer I think.

I'm using Flying Saucer as follows:

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -cp .:$FS_PATH/acts_as_flying_saucer/lib/java/bin:$FS_PATH/acts_as_flying_saucer/lib/java/jar/minium.jar:$FS_PATH/acts_as_flying_saucer/lib/java/jar/itext-paulo-155.jar:$FS_PATH/acts_as_flying_saucer/lib/java/jar/core-renderer.jar:$FS_PATH/acts_as_flying_saucer/lib/java/jar/java-getopt-1.0.13.jar Xhtml2Pdf /home/max/font_test.html /home/max/font_test.pdf
```

Can anyone see if I'm doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question here in case anyone else makes the same mistake.  The answer turned out to be really simple - it's not in the font!  Turns out that the "₹" symbol was only invented in 2010, and so is not present in a lot of Unicode font files, including the one I used.

It worked in the browser because the browser (Chrome) was automatically looking for it in other character sets (without me explicitly asking it to), and found it in Deja Vu Sans as it happens (the fallback for Linux Chromium).

I changed my code to use the older (but still acceptable) "₨" symbol, but a more proper fix would be to include a font that actually has the modern Rupees symbol.

Comment: Thank you. This turned out to be my issue as well. For future troubleshooters who find this StackOverflow page, I was able to determine conclusively that the font was missing characters by running it through Microsoft's font validator: https://github.com/microsoft/Font-Validator